# Android JSON Exception End of Input

Tags: android, html, json, parsing, input

I have been trying to parse a JSON object for quite some time. There are many similar questions to this on here however none have had an answer that works. None of my code is confidential so I am posting here.

public class JSONParser {

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
              //  is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line);
        }
        is.close();


        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
        jObj = new JSONObject(tokener);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

*edited Get was necessary instead of Post

Comment: Try UTF-8 and/or don't add the `\n` in the `sb.append`

Comment: first do not add \n, JSON doesn't have new lines

Comment: @Shehabix, that's not the correct reason. JSON can have as much whitespace as needed to make it readable. However, in the above code, there's no guarantee that readLine returns full lines at proper line breaks, as the source url doesn't seem to have line breaks.

Comment: @323go yes you're right, I mean inside the content not between objects.

Comment: I edited the parsing class to suggestions but still receiving end of input error character 0 as before. Edited code in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little test app and ran it.  HTTPPost returns nothing, but if you switch it to HTTPGet, you get a valid response.

After that, the first element in the array is missing the "name", so when you call `c.getString("name")`, a JSONException is generated which it looks like you are just catching in an outer block.  You'll need to add some exception handling for each `getString` call, maybe something like:

```
String name = null;
try {
name = c.getString("name");
} catch(JSONException e) {
//name is missing!
name = "";
}
```

Comment: Found this last night but wouldn't let me post to question. This is indeed the problem. Also the name is within an inner object and has to be parsed separately.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept my answer as correct, or if you want to provide more detail you can answer your own question and accept your answer as correct.  Either way, it is good form to accept an answer to your correctly answered question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong with yours, but maybe compare with mine that I have been using that works. I will say that I had the input character 0 error and it was a **SERVER SIDE** error, not with my parsing. It means that data returned probably wasn't able to be encoded in a JSON object. If I remember correctly, I think my server was returning nothing, and I was basically trying to parse `nothing`. I'd verify what you're getting from your server.

```
String result;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value");
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "value2");

try
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // URL to POST to
    HttpPost httpreq = new HttpPost("www.sample.com/file.php");
    httpreq.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpreq);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();

    result = sb.toString();
            /* if you print 'result' you should see valid data 
               if your server is working */
            // System.out.println(result); 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle what went wrong
}

JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

if (jsonArray != null)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
   {
       JSONObject json_data;
       try
       {
           json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           String value = json_data.getString("json_key_here");                
       }
       catch (JSONException e)
       {
            // handle what went wrong
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: The code does not error until I am trying to parse the string into a json object. I put a log of the string result right before that and it did not print, so it is indeed empty. There is however an ios app using this particular json feed already so I do not believe the issue could be server side....

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you take the entity, convert it to a BufferedReader reading the entity one line at a time, convert that to a String, convert the String to a JSONTokener, then finally create a JSONObject using the tokener.

Here's a simpler way to do it:

```
String entityString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(entityString);
```

If that throws an exception, then catch it with output:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And show us that trace.